# Let $f$ be differentiable. Show that if $\lim_{\to\infty}()= \in\mathbb R$ then $\lim_{\to\infty}′()=0.$ Provided the latter exists.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f$ be differentiable. Show that if $\lim_{\to\infty}()= \in\mathbb R$ then $\lim_{\to\infty}′()=0.$ Provided the latter exists.

I can't think of an idea to solve this. I tried using the epsilon-delta definition, but I couldn't go through it.

Comment: You need to show that $f(x)$ and $f(x+h)$ are sufficiently close to each other when $x$ is large.

Comment: A reason you need the limit to exist: $$f(x)=\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x}$$ is a counter-example with no limit for $f’.$

Comment: If the limit would be different from $0$, $f$ would be monotone increasing or decreasing with speed away from $0$. So $f$ can't get constant at infinity.

Comment: For this question, as is, the issue of how math is displayed is somewhat trivial.  However, going forward, please use [mathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to display math.

Comment: The key is the mean value theorem.

Comment: For what it's worth, I just tried to edit the title of your question and failed.  I ran into the upper limit on the number of characters that can occur in the title.  mathSE reviewers will prefer that you use mathJax, even in the title, and have the title briefly describe what your question will be about.  Then, place the explicit question that needs to be attacked in the body of your question.  I thought that it would be going too far for me to high-handedly alter your title and question.  However, I suggest that you do edit it.

Comment: mathSE reviewers will probably react negatively to your posting, as is.  For an explanation of why, see [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).  Personally, my first try, which might not succeed, would be to write out the underlying definitions of what the premises are, and the underlying definition of what conclusion that you are supposed to achieve.  I am not saying that this will work.  Further, even if it works, it may well be challenging.  However, this would be my first try.

Comment: @user2661923 the secret to such a title length issue is that the title is too long, and your edit should include trimming the title, too. Titles should not really be the entire question.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I agree, but I was trying to *engage* the OP into doing that.  Then, I hoped to engage the OP into attacking the question and documenting his attack.  The best laid plans...

Answer (score 0):

Start with the hypothesis that $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = L$.  Now suppose we fix some $\varepsilon > 0$.  Then there exists some $R$ such that whenever $x \ge R$, we have $|f(x) - L| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$.  Then we can conclude that $|f(R+1) - f(R)| \le \varepsilon$.

Apply the Mean Value Theorem to get that there exists some $x \in (R, R+1)$ such that $f'(x) = \frac{f(R+1) - f(R)}{(R+1)-R} = f(R+1) - f(R)$; therefore, $|f'(x)| \le \varepsilon$.  In fact, with some slight adjustments to this argument, you can show that there exists arbitrarily large $x$ such that $|f'(x)| \le \varepsilon$.

This suggests to prove a lemma: suppose $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is such that $\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x)$ exists, and also is such that for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists arbitrarily large $x$ with $|g(x)| \le \varepsilon$.  Then in fact $\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x) = 0$.  I will leave the proof of this lemma as an exercise for the reader.  Now, applying this lemma to the case of $g = f'$ will conclude the proof of the originally desired result.